# Does a verb phrase always function as a predicate?

Tags: predicate

> *What **is obvious** is that we are choosing a new path.*

Does the VP (***is obvious***) function as a predicate?

If it does, is there any situation where a VP doesn't function as a predicate? Or does a VP always function as a predicate?

### EDIT

Another example would be:

> *I took a train **heading north**.*

Here, does the VP ***heading north*** function as a predicate?

Comment: It certainly functions as a predicate in the example sentence. However, note that the form of the sentence is a _Wh_-Cleft, which makes a whole noun clause (_that we are choosing a new path_) into a predicate nominal (with _is_ as an auxiliary), and makes another noun clause (_What is obvious_) into the subject of this predicate. This is a highly complex construction, with its own special syntax. Not a simple example at all. As to the question, yes, VPs are always predicates; they are they syntactic equivalent of logical 'predicate', like sentences are the equivalent of logical 'proposition'.

Comment: @JohnLawler _What is obvious_ is not a clause but a noun phrase (NP). It's equivalent to _the thing which is obvious_, which is an NP that includes a relative clause _which is obvious_.

Comment: Is *is obvious* a "verb phrase"?

Comment: Yes, _is obvious_ is a [verb phrase](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf). JK2, syntax can be done using derivations; branding constituents is not a humane practice. You have your terminology and are encouraged to use it; I have mine and can understand yours, though I find it wanting.

Comment: @JohnLawler I don't know if you can simply dismiss it as "terminology". If you start calling _What is obvious_ in the OP a clause, then you're essentially objecting to the proposition that the predicate of a clause is the head of the clause, because clearly _is obvious_ is not the head of _What is obvious_ but that of _is obvious_ in the OP.

Comment: @JK2:  Not at all. _What is obvious_ has a subject, a verb inflected to agree with it, and a predicate adjective. That's a clause. What it is equivalent to is semantics; call it a _wh_-clause if you're squeamish, but it's a clause, and it's being used as a noun. That's an NP over an S, never mind the heads. Heads are not necessary unless you're making curry.

Comment: @JohnLawler I'm curious. I'm not sure what it is that you object to. Do you object to the proposition (1) that the predicate of a clause is the head of the clause (which I think is something that is agreed upon across the board in linguistics)? Or do you object to the proposition (2) that the head of the OP's _What is obvious_ is not _is obvious_ but _What_?

Comment: I don't think that "head" is defined in any useful way, so I don't use it. I wouldn't say I object to either statement, but I find them both irrelevant to English syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (1) [*What **is obvious***] *is that we are choosing a new path*.
>
> (2) *I took a train* ***heading north***.

Yes, in (1) "is obvious" is the predicate in the bracketed NP -- a fused relative construction meaning "that which is obvious".

And in (2) "heading north" is predicate in the bracketed gerund-participial clause modifying "train".

But VPs are not always predicates. They can occur as attributive modifiers in NPs, e.g. "a sleeping child", where "sleeping" is not a clause and hence "sleeping", although a VP, is not functioning as a predicate. The rationale behind this is that the structural possibilities are too restricted to justify a clausal analysis: you can’t have a subject and you can’t have a post-verbal dependent.

Comment: Thanks for the "sleeping child" example. What do you think about "frequently asked questions"? Does "frequently asked" qualify as a predicate?

Comment: @JK2  I'd put that in the same category as "sleeping", i.e. a VP as an attributive modifier.